# expected vs actual in system.assertEquals is reverse

Tags: unit-test

When my test fails, the error message seems to reverse the meaning of Expected and Actual, and so I want to clarify if this is normal.

I am running my tests in the developer console.

Assert statement:

```
System.assertEquals(donorOppIds.size(), 3, 'donor opp size is wrong');
```

Error message

```
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: donor opp size is wrong: Expected: 2, Actual: 3
```

Actual to me would be the result obtained by running the test, but if that was the case, then the assert would pass.

After reading through the code, I see that the set size should indeed be 2 - and updating to assertEquals 2 passes

So is the error message reversing Expected and Actual.  Or is this working as designed?

Comment: `expected` is the 1st arg so the error message is correct. You transposed the values being passed to the call: it should be `System.assertEquals(3, donorOppIds.size(), 'donor opp size is wrong')`

Comment: ahh!!!  this was written by someone back c. 2008 and every single one of the asserts are written transposed!!! thanks for clarifying.

Comment: One of the least understood features of newer devs. Time to fix some code.